apache mod_php vs php_fpm - huge difference in load time, but only for Wordpress website
I have a Wordpress website, it was set up as nginx proxy apache mod_php.
Load time was over 2.5 seconds, so I tried several ways to speed it up.
Finally I tried php_fpm and voila - the website loaded for 0.5 sec.
By load time, I mean how much time it takes the html to be loaded.
Note the website has no traffic at all.
Why is this huge difference?
In the past, I made several performance tests of php-fpm vs apache behind nginx.
I never tested Wordpress, but I did test laravel, simphony, custom websites, you name it.
I never saw a difference more than 1-2 % in the load time.
Note if I use brand new installed Wordpress, without plugins and bloatware, load time on apache behind nginx is 0.1-0.2 seconds.
Can anyone explain to me where this huge difference in load times comes from?
My theory is Wordpress uses several php files, also probably scans several directories for files in order to produce the HTML. However I can not verify this :(
